# R question: epiR and the epi.2by2 function: unable to load the dependency, zexact

Tags: r

I am using R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt) with R Studio version 2023.12.0, on Windows 11.

I am unable to load the Zexact function when using epiR and the epi.2by2 function. When I run the command I get the following error message as shown by the example:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
dat <- c(24,14,137,222) # a,b,c,d

epi.2by2(dat = dat, method = "cross.sectional", conf.level = 0.95, units = 1, 
   interpret = FALSE, outcome = "as.columns")
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Error in zexact(as.matrix(cbind(a, N1)), conf.level = conf.level) : 
  could not find function "zexact"
```

I installed epiR with al dependencies and that did not solve the issue. More generally, I am looking for good R packages for multiple, stratified 2x2 table analyses and would be grateful for any other recommendations.

Thank you,

Garth Rauscher
UIC School of Public Health
Chicago, IL

Answer (score 0):

i was able to reproduce this and install the `epiR` package, and the code worked. maybe try uninstalling the epiR package with `remove.packages("epiR")` and try reinstalling it again, if you do not have the latest version of the package.

```
> library(epiR)
Loading required package: survival
Package epiR 2.0.66 is loaded
Type help(epi.about) for summary information
Type browseVignettes(package = 'epiR') to learn how to use epiR for applied epidemiological analyses


> 
> 
> # Your data
> dat <- c(24, 14, 137, 222)
> 
> # Run epi.2by2
> epi.2by2(dat = dat, method = "cross.sectional", conf.level = 0.95, units = 1,
+          interpret = FALSE, outcome = "as.columns")
             Outcome +    Outcome -      Total               Prev risk *
Exposed +           24           14         38       0.63 (0.46 to 0.78)
Exposed -          137          222        359       0.38 (0.33 to 0.43)
Total              161          236        397       0.41 (0.36 to 0.46)

Point estimates and 95% CIs:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Prev risk ratio                                1.66 (1.26, 2.18)
Prev odds ratio                                2.78 (1.39, 5.55)
Attrib prev in the exposed *                   0.25 (0.09, 0.41)
Attrib fraction in the exposed (%)            39.58 (20.35, 54.16)
Attrib prev in the population *                0.02 (-0.05, 0.09)
Attrib fraction in the population (%)         5.90 (1.58, 10.03)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Uncorrected chi2 test that OR = 1: chi2(1) = 8.906 Pr>chi2 = 0.003
Fisher exact test that OR = 1: Pr>chi2 = 0.005
 Wald confidence limits
 CI: confidence interval
 * Outcomes per population unit 
>
```